# load data from controller when modal window opens up

Tags: laravel-5, bootstrap-modal

I am using laravel 5.4

I open a modal window inside a page.  but i don't want to load all the data at the first beginning 
I want to load some data only when the modal window opens
and then use this returned data for some if conditions inside the blade.. is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using JavaScript. The main idea is that when the system fires the modal, it will call a JavaScript function that will call a `GET` method to receive a rendered Blade partial and append it in a div inside the modal.

The main IDEA is something like this:

View File:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-id" onclick="getFunction();"> 
    Open Modal
</a>

<div class="modal" id="modal-id">
    <div id="modal-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function getFunction() {
    $('#modal-content').empty();
    $.get( "/get/content", function( data ) {
        $('#modal-content').append(data);
    });
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/get/content', 'ContentController@getContent');
```

Controller:

```
public function getContent(Request $request)
{
    return view('contents.partial')->render();
}
```

And then you are going to create a new Blade file with a partial. This is going to be the content of the modal. In this example, the file is in views/contents/partial:

```
<h2>Content header</h2>
<p>Content text</p>
```

Since you didn't post any code, I'm answering with the main idea. You just have to add your needs to this code.